# Remainders of repeating digits

Tags: elementary-number-theory

What will be the remainder when $122333444455555\ldots1313141414141$(Total of $100$ terms)divided by $7$?

My method is that the above sequence can be written as $10^{99} + 22\times10^{97} +333\times10^{94}+\cdots$ after individually dividing the terms by $7$, I get $4$ as the remainder. Can someone please suggest any other less time-consuming method?

Note : $100$ terms means the last pattern will be $141414141$. All the $2$-digit numbers like $10,11,12,13,14,\ldots$ so on will be considered one term and repetition of these one terms(along with the terms $1223334444\ldots$ will continue till the count of all the terms reaches $100$.

Comment: Your question and the tags are not very related. Elementary number theory tag, however, makes much more sense.

Comment: Could you explain the remark "$100$ terms means the last $4$ digits will be $4141$"?

Comment: It means upto 9 numeral we have 45 numbers..after that we have 10s 10 times,11s 11 times so on till 14..the 14s occupy the last 9 terms left to make 100 terms.. Hence 141414141

Comment: 10 is considered one term and not two.I have made the edit in the question..

Comment: Your edit says that we can count $10$ as one term and not two... are we counting $11$ as one term as well and not two?  what about $13$ and $14$?  Why would the last digit be a one and not a four if fourteen is counted as a single term why cut it off before finishing writing the term?

Comment: We already know how your number begins. Why don't you write the last 30 or so digits to make it clear how it ends? Apparently you mean that the number has exactly one hundred digits? Is that correct?

Comment: Which of these is the number you intend?  Or is neither the number you intend and why not: $\overbrace{1223334444\dots \underbrace{9\dots 9}_{9~\text{times}}\underbrace{10\dots 10}_{10~\text{times}}\underbrace{11\dots 11}_{11~\text{times}}1212121212121}^{\text{a total of}~100~\text{digits}}$


$\overbrace{1223334444\dots \underbrace{9\dots 9}_{9 ~\text{terms}}\underbrace{10\dots 10}_{10~\text{terms}} \dots\underbrace{13\dots 13}_{13~\text{terms}} \underbrace{141414141414141414}_{9~ \text{"terms"}} }^{155~ \text{digits but}~100~\text{"terms"}}$

Comment: First one is the number I intend..

Comment: @ghostrider That directly contradicts your final paragraph where you say the two digit numbers count as "one term each".  If the first number I wrote is indeed what you mean then as mentioned already, it doesn't make it to the 14's, it stops in the middle of the 12's.  The total number of **digits** used in the number one 1's, two 2's, ... ten 10's, eleven 11's will be $1+2+\dots+9+\color{red}{2}\cdot 10 + \color{red}{2}\cdot 11 = 87$ digits, leaving 13 digits to be used in the middle of the twelves.  In that case, you should edit your question. Otherwise you should rescind that last comment.

Comment: I think I understand what the OP might mean:  When you get to the two-digit numbers, you give $10$ digits to repeating "10," $11$ digits to repeating "11," which means the last repetition gets cut off, etc.  Note that $1+2+\cdots+13=91$, which is why you only get four and a half repetitions of "14" (for the final $9$ digits of the $100$-digit number).  The one glitch here is that, with this interpretation, the number ends $...1313131313131141414141$, with *two* "1's" between the final 3 and the first 4.  I think the OP should just write out all $100$ digits, so we can see exactly what's meant.

Comment: You might start by subtracting multiples of 1,001 (= 7 x 143) wherever possible.  For example, the first 6 digits 122333 reduce to 211.